# First-order non-linear differential equation and transcendental equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, inverse-function, transcendental-equations

I'm trying to solve this differential equation : 
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{-2 y^3}{(y+1)^2(y+2)^2} $$
with the boundary condition $y(x_0)=x_0$, $x>0$, and $y(x)$ being a positive function.
The integration of the equation is straightforward,  however after integration, one gets a transcendental equation of the form $$a y(x)+by^2(x)+c \log(y)+\frac{d}{y}+\frac{e}{y^2}+ g(x_0)= z (x-x_0)$$ 
where $a,b,c , d, e,z $ are constants, and $g(x_0) $ is a function of $x_0$.
I tried to solve it with Lagrange inversion theorem, however due to the non triviality of the LHS, the computation of the $n$'th derivative is very complicated, is there any other way to solve it ?

Comment: It's hard enough to solve $y+\log y=x$ for $y$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson in the litterature solutions of $a y^2 + b y +c log(y)=x+e$ are found, only the $1/y and 1/y^2 $ are making it hard

Comment: Really? What's the solution of $y+\log y=x$? It must involve the Lambert $W$-function, right?

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353055/first-order-non-linear-differential-equation-and-transcendental-equation without notifying either site, an abuse of the system.

Comment: I still don't see your solution to $y+\log y=x$.

Comment: Are you still here, Giuseppe?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a purely numerical problem which does not require much.

What you obtained is
$$x=-\frac{y^2}{2}-6 y+\frac{12}{y}+\frac{2}{y^2}-13 \log (y)+ C \tag1$$ and the initial conditions make
$$C=\frac{y_0^2}{2}+6 y_0-\frac{12}{y_0}-\frac{2}{y_0^2}+13 \log (y_0)+x_0\tag2$$
For a given value of $x$, you want to compute $y$ that is to say to find the zero of function
$$f(y)=-\frac{y^2}{2}-6 y+\frac{12}{y}+\frac{2}{y^2}-13 \log (y)+(C-x)\tag3$$

$f(y)$ is quite nice since its derivative never cancels and the solution is unique which means that any equation solver will do the job, the only potential problem being to find a "reasonable" starting guess. To get it, I should use a marching process (or a golden search) until I find a value $y_*$ such that $f(y_*)\, f''(y_*) >0$ in order, by Darboux theorem, to avoid any overshoot of the solution if Newton method (the simplest one) has to be used.

Notice that, $y$ being supposed to be positive (as in must be because of the logarithmic term)
$$f''(y)=\frac{12}{y^4}+\frac{24}{y^3}+\frac{13}{y^2}-1$$ is positive for $0< y <\frac{1}{2} \left(3+\sqrt{33}\right)$ and negative if $y >\frac{1}{2} \left(3+\sqrt{33}\right)$.